# how to offset scrollIntoView()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a React application and have this function which works to scroll to a div, but it is just slightly off so I need to have it scroll up by 20px or so when it goes to the correct div.

```
     class CountryDropdown extends Component{

    handleScroll = (country) => {

        document.getElementById(country).scrollIntoView({
            block: "start",
            behavior: "smooth"
          })

      }

    render () {
    return (
        <Dropdown text='Jump to Country'>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Dropdown.Item flag='fr' text='France' onClick={() => this.handleScroll("france")}/>
                <Dropdown.Item flag='es' text='Spain' onClick={() => this.handleScroll("spain")}/>
                <Dropdown.Item flag='pt' text='Portugal' onClick={() => this.handleScroll("portugal")}/>
                <Dropdown.Item flag='gr' text='Greece' onClick={() => this.handleScroll("greece")}/>
                <Dropdown.Item flag='de' text='Germany' onClick={() => this.handleScroll("germany")}/>
                <Dropdown.Item flag='at' text='Austria' onClick={() => this.handleScroll("austria")}/>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    );
}
}


 export default CountryDropdown;
```

Comment: Hi Elaine! Just wrote an answer for you, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherNgo I actually tried that before and it doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if it's because React is asynchronous? I tried to wrap it in a .then statement, but couldn't get that to work...